# WSO2 ESB 5.0 publishEvent Mediator not working inside sequences invoked by Clone Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I use `publishEvent` from a sequence works OK, but if I try to publish from a Clone mediator, this error happens.

> TID: [-1] [] [2016-09-11 01:57:29,777] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.publishevent.PublishEventMediator} -  Cannot
>   mediate message. Failed to load event sink 'Monitor'. Error: Event
>   sink "Monit or" not found
>   {org.wso2.carbon.mediator.publishevent.PublishEventMediator}
>   org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Event sink "Monitor" not found

Can be the same error than this, but with Clone? https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4420

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. I have reported a jira(https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4899) to track this. It'll be fixed in future releases.

Thanks.